# Printing fizzy lines

Tags: beginner, c, programming-challenge, io, fizzbuzz

#### Challenge

Given a test case print out a FizzBuzz Series.

#### Specifications

1. The first argument is a path to a file.
2. Each line includes a test case.
3. Each test case is comprised of three spaced delimited integers.

   - The first two integers are the dividers X and Y.
   - The third integer, N is how far to count.
4. Print out the series 1 through N, replacing numbers divisible by X with F, numbers divisible by Y with B and numbers divisible by both with FB.

#### Constraints

1. The input file is formatted correctly.
2. The numbers are valid positive integers.
3. X is in range [1, 20]
4. Y is in range [1, 20]
5. N is in range [21, 100]
6. Output should be one line per set with no trailing or empty spaces.

**Input Sample**

> 3 5 10
> 2 7 15

**Output Sample**

> 1 2 F 4 B F 7 8 F B
> 1 F 3 F 5 F B F 9 F 11 F 13 FB 15

[Source](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/1/)

My Solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_buzzified(int fizz, int buzz, int count) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
        if (i % fizz == 0 && i % buzz == 0) {
            printf("%s", "FB");
        } else if (i % fizz == 0) {
            printf("%s", "F");
        } else if (i % buzz == 0) {
            printf("%s", "B");
        } else {
            printf("%d", i);
        }

        printf(i < count ? " " : "\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    FILE *file;
    if (argc < 2 || !(file = fopen(argv[1], "r"))) {
        puts("No argument provided / File not found.");
        return 1;
    }

    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    int fizz;
    int buzz;
    int count;

    while (!feof(file)) {
        fscanf(file, "%d %d %d", &fizz, &buzz, &count);
        print_buzzified(fizz, buzz, count);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Design:

- Good job on setting up everything in `main()`, then passing off control to another function.
- Declare *and* initialize `file` **after** checking the command line arguments.
- Initialize `fizz`, `buzz`, and `count`.
- Don't use `!feof(file)` to control your loop.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26557243/1937270) for more details.
- Check the return value of `fscanf()` to make sure we're reading good data.
- Good job remembering to close the file.

### Readability & Maintainability/Performance

I'm grouping these two categories together for this review, since they happen to go hand in hand.

- Your `for` loop can be refactored down a bit:

  ```
  if (i % fizz == 0) fputc('F', stdout);
  if (i % buzz == 0) fputc('B', stdout);
  if (i % fizz && i % buzz)) fprintf(stdout, "%d", i);
  ```

  Some people may find issue with the duplicated check on `i` with `fizz` and `buzz`, but we cut out some conditional branches doing this and the more branches we cut, the less susceptible to [branch prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor) we are.  There may be a better way to write this, but I can't think of it right now.
- Note how I used `fputs()` and `fputc()` in the code above instead of `printf()`.  This is because those functions are \$ O(1) \$ operations instead of \$ O(n) \$ to loop over the string and format it.  This may speed up your program by a hair, if that, but the main reason I recommend this change is to make clear we aren't modifying any strings.
- Since the range of \$ X \$, \$ Y \$, and \$ N \$ is 1-20, it would be good to change the type representing these variables to something a bit more compact in memory.

  Depending on what we want to optimize for (memory or performance), I would recommend either `uint_least8_t` or `uint_fast8_t`.

  1. `uint_least8_t`: give me the smallest type of `unsigned int` which has at least 8 bits. Optimize for memory consumption.
  2. `uint_fast8_t`: give me an `unsigned int` of at least 8 bits. Pick a larger type if it will make my program faster, because of alignment considerations. Optimize for speed.

Comment: 1) Good optimizing compilers will create the same code with `fputs("B")`,  `fputc('B')` and `printf("%s", "B");` so performance gain may be moot.  Better to write for clarity and let the compiler optimize.  2) Minor: Although "Initialize fizz, buzz, and count." has some value, it is not needed nearly as much as checking the result of `fscanf()`.  Moving these 3 to within the loop could also be considered. As OP's given's include well formed input and this is test driver code anyways - not much of an issue.  All-in-all nice review.

Comment: Using `uint8_t` versus `int` or `unsigned` may save data memory but not likely performance as typically code performs "best" at `int/unsigned`.   Still worth considering had there been large amounts of such data.